# Large matrix operation in R with bigalgebra

Tags: r

I want to multiply two large matrices and apply a column-wise function to the resulting matrix. Given that I do not have enough memory to allocate these objects, I tried the `bigalgebra` package which allows to compute some matrices operations but not the one needed here.

My script looks like this:

```
library(bigalgebra)

X <- as.big.matrix( matrix(rnorm(265225*360), nrow = 265225, ncol = 360) )
Y <- as.big.matrix( matrix(rnorm(360*10000),  nrow = 360,    ncol = 265225) )
Z <- X %*% Y # Z is a big.matrix object

apply(Z, 2, function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2)))
# > Error: in as.vector(data) : no method for coercing this s4 to class to a vector

apply(as.matrix(Z), 2, function(x) sqrt(sum(x^2)))
# > Error: cannot allocate vector of size 19.5 Gb
```

How can I deal with this object? And, is there a better way / faster to achieve the same result?

Comment: Just do `library(biganalytics)` and your first `apply` call works.

Comment: @Roland fantastic! and is there a way to improve the speed of this computation?

Comment: @李哲源 thanks that improves the speed, but I was referring mainly to the matrix multiplication operation

Comment: To make the matrix multiplication faster you will need more memory or at least a faster disk. This operation is bound by the speed the matrix elements are moved to the CPU.